# Sequelize correctly executing multiple creates + updates

Tags: promise, sequelize.js

I have a cron job that scrapes a list of items on a website and then inserts or updates records in a database.  When I scrape the page, I want to create records for new ones that haven't been created yet, otherwise update any existing ones.  Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
// pretend there is a "Widget" model defined

function createOrUpdateWidget(widgetConfig) {
    return Widget.find(widgetConfig.id)
        .then(function(widget) {
            if (widget === null) {
                return Widget.create(widgetConfig);
            }
            else {
                widget.updateAttributes(widgetConfig);
            }
        });
}

function createOrUpdateWidgets(widgetConfigObjects) {
    var promises = [];

    widgetConfigObjects.forEach(function(widgetConfig) {
        promises.push(createOrUpdateWidget(widgetConfig));
    });

    return Sequelize.Promise.all(promises);
}


createOrUpdateWidgets([...])
    .done(function() {
        console.log('Done!');
    });
```

This seems to work fine, but I'm not sure if I'm doing this "correctly" or not.  Do all promises that perform DB interactions need to run serially, or is how I have them defined ok?  Is there a better way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: Thank you for the logic alone. Struggling with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're doing is pretty idiomatic and perfectly fine, the only room for improvement is to utilize the fact Sequelize uses Bluebird for promises so you get `.map` for free, which lets you convert:

```
function createOrUpdateWidgets(widgetConfigObjects) {
    var promises = [];

    widgetConfigObjects.forEach(function(widgetConfig) {
        promises.push(createOrUpdateWidget(widgetConfig));
    });

    return Sequelize.Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Into:

```
function createOrUpdateWidgets(widgetConfigObjects) {
    return Sequelize.Promise.map(widgetConfig, createOrUpdateWidget)
}
```

Other than that minor improvement - you're chaining promises correctly and seem to have the correct hang of it.

Comment: In terms of interaction with the database, are having all these separate "parallel" promises "safe"?  As opposed to daisy chaining them in a serial manner.

Comment: @chinabuffet yes, you have no guarantee on the execution order though - that is one might execute before the other. If you'd like to chain them in a sequential matter, you can swap `Promise.map` for `Promise.each` but I don't think it'd matter much in this case as the updates aren't related.